# Error shows Invalid type for value: array when update customer image using rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Errors create/update customer image using REST API in magento2?

I searched a lot on google but not getting any solution for this.

Please help me in this.
[image]

Comment: please share your API interface code, u have added string type there in comment while passing an array value.

Comment: @sudo55 plz help how to add API interface code in custom module of  custom attribute of customer. I am no knowledge how to add interface code

Comment: ok, interface code will be in module's Api folder. check there.